# Organic vs Paid Attribution Model (Granger)

Tags: time-series, predictive-models, arma

I'm wondering if there is literature or studies done on how to model organic attribution from paid user acquisition.

So the context is, on our mobile app, we have paid installs that we purchase and organic installs, but we believe organic installs mostly come from either featuring or referrals from current users. Thus, for every paid user we buy, we actually can attribute some organic installs to that paid user.

My problem then is what this coefficient is. My first instinct is to use granger causality model where the lagged organic installs and paid installs are the inputs to the model (along with exogenous featured dates).

So basically there are two time series: organic installs $y_t$ and paid installs $x_t$, and I regress organic installs on lagged organic installs and paid installs and exogenous featuring $z_t$ on the dates we were featured.

\begin{equation}  y_t=\beta_0+\beta_1 y_{t-1}+ ... + \beta_q y_{t-q} + \gamma_1 x_{t-1} + ... + \gamma_q x_{t-q} +\delta_0 z_t+\varepsilon_t \end{equation}

So basically is this a valid way to model this problem and if so, is an information criterion like AIC or BIC the best way to determine the order?

Anyways, would love to hear everyone's thoughts or suggestions if there's a well-defined model for this!

Comment: So I think it can be generalized outside of marketing to just two time series: organic installs and paid installs where users churn over time.

Then, how do I predict the value of the first time series, organic installs, given the past time series of organic and paid installs given the assumption that most of the organic installs are a direct result of current users in the game (the non-churned previous organic and paid installs).

Comment: I tried to better specify the problem in the question, does it make more sense now?

Comment: The question is not completely clear to me. So in essence, you want to calculate how many installs one paid user brings? You have variables $y_t$ (organic installs), $x_t$ (paid installs) and $z_t$ (featuring), you have a model like $$y_t=\beta_0+\beta_1 y_{t-1}+\gamma_0 x_t+\delta_0 z_t+\varepsilon_t$$ and want to find out $\gamma_0$?

Comment: Yes, the only thing I would change is that I would use the time series of organic and paid installs since users will stay in the game beyond one day and continue to refer organic installs. This is assuming a relatively constant retention curve for the users over time though, which I think is fine for this purpose. Then, I'd probably calculate the sum of all \begin{equation}\gamma_n\end{equation}

Comment: I'm also wondering how I would choose the order for such a model if it's appropriate.

Comment: *I would use the time series of organic and paid installs*. Hmm, am I not doing that in the model? Could you try editing your post by typing in your model the way you see it?

Comment: Yeah sorry, so something like: \begin{equation}

y_t=\beta_0+\beta_1 y_{t-1}+ ... + \beta_q y_{t-q} + \gamma_1 x_{t-1} + ... + \gamma_q x_{t-q} +\delta_0 z_t+\varepsilon_t \end{equation} where $z_t$ is just a dummy variable indicating whether the game was featured on date $t$

Comment: OK, could you include this in the original post? That could make it much clearer. Also, what is your question then? How to utilize the model for estimating some effect (what exactly?) or testing some hypothesis (what exactly?)?

Comment: Yea basically I want to estimate the sum of the $\gamma_n$ coefficients to determine how many additional installs a paid user generates, so we can estimate the value of a paid user more accurately, and I'm wondering is this a valid model? Has this been done before and is there another standard model that already exists to do this?